# Why is my amortization program stopping early for seemingly no reason?

Tags: java, loops, amortization

[PLEASE READ] EDIT: The problem has been narrowed down to the fact that I am calculating the amount of payments necessary inaccurately. I am now in need of a way to calculate the number of payments required to pay off x amount of loan, with y amount interest, and z amount paid per month only. My initial approach was to take the monthly payment provided by the user (e.g. $250) with an interest rate (e.g. 13.5%) to pay off a loan (e.g. $1000) and get the amount paid per interested month (worded weirdly, I know) Thus you'd get:

250 - 250 * 0.135 = 216.25

Then divide the total loan by that number, so

1000 / 216.25 = 4.62

Then ceil the value to get 5 total payments. This worked for the example just given, as you can see in the code at the bottom of my post, but if we take for example:

$200,000 loan, 6% interest rate, and payments of $1500 per month, we get:

1500 - 1500 * 0.06 = 1410

And then:

$200,000 / 1410 = 141.8 ish

Thus the amount of payments (according to this calculation) should be 142. However, that is drastically incorrect, as you can see in the comments thread. Through trial and error, the correct number of payments is actually 221, and I haven't been able to attain this value using any calculations so far. Hence the following:

tl;dr - I need a way to accurately calculate the number of payments in an amortization using only the initial loan amount, the interest rate, and the proposed amount paid per month.

Thanks in advance, and this def narrows down the problem.

---

[ORIGINAL POST] I've created a program that does amortization charts for my AP Compsci Class. Everything was running smoothly until I tell the program to handle bigger numbers. For some reason, the program just halts at a certain value and I can't figure out why. I was hoping someone on here could help me debug it.

I use intelliJ for my IDE, and I don't know what other info would really help here.

First of all: Yes, I know I should use ArrayList instead of a 1d array, I started this before we learned about them in class and I don't feel like redoing it. I just want to know the problems with my existing code so I can hand it in and be done with it. The only requirement is for it to function properly. Yes, I know the code utterly sucks, I don't want to hear it please. Just looking for the problem with my existing code. Yes, I know I suck at coding. Please don't roast ;-;

Tried commenting out the loop, literally calculating it by hand, going through step by step, etc. Can't seem to draw any conclusion.

Here is the method:

```
public static void amortization(){

        int[] info = new int[10000000];

        double Lamt;
        double IRate;
        double MRate;
        double payMonth;
        double firstlyMonth;
        double interestedSub;
        double interestedAmt;
        double amtPayments;
        double mPayment;
        double iPayment;
        double pPayment;
        double pBalance;
        double q;
        double finalMPymt;
        double finalIPymt;
        double finalPPymt;
        double finalPBalance;


        Scanner amortkey = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the following values:");
        System.out.println("Loan amount:");
        Lamt=amortkey.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Annual Interest Rate, in decimal form:");
        IRate=amortkey.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Monthly Payment Amount:");
        payMonth=amortkey.nextDouble();

        interestedSub=payMonth * IRate;
        interestedAmt=payMonth - interestedSub;
        firstlyMonth=Lamt / interestedAmt;
        amtPayments=Math.ceil(firstlyMonth);

        MRate=IRate / 12;

        for(int a=0; a<amtPayments; a++){
            info[a]=a+1;
        }


        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("     PAYMENT          MONTHLY          INTEREST          PRINCIPAL          PRINCIPAL");
        System.out.println("     NUMBER           PAYMENT          PAYMENT           PAYMENT             BALANCE");
        System.out.println();

        pBalance=Lamt; //1000


        //THIS LOOP DETERMINES THE CHART
        for(int b=0; b<amtPayments-1; b++){//b starts 0, must climb to the payments that must be made.

            iPayment=pBalance * MRate; //calculate interest payment by taking the rate portion of the principal away.
            pPayment=payMonth - iPayment;//calculate principal payment independently from total month pay
            q=pBalance - pPayment;//calculate new balance of principal, q
            mPayment=iPayment + pPayment;//make monthly payment equal to whatever the principal is plus the interest owed
            pBalance=q;//reset the loop with a new principal balance

            System.out.println("       " + info[b] + "               " + Math.round(mPayment * 100.00) / 100.00 + "            " + Math.round(iPayment * 100.00) / 100.00 + "              " + Math.round(pPayment * 100.00) / 100.00 + "               " + Math.round(pBalance * 100.00) / 100.00);
            System.out.println();


            if(pBalance<mPayment){

                finalIPymt=pBalance * MRate;
                finalMPymt=pBalance + finalIPymt;
                finalPPymt=pBalance;
                finalPBalance=0;
                System.out.println("       " + info[b+1] + "               " + Math.round(finalMPymt * 100.00) / 100.00 + "            " + Math.round(finalIPymt * 100.00) / 100.00 + "              " + Math.round(finalPPymt * 100.00) / 100.00 + "               " + Math.round(finalPBalance * 100.00) / 100.00);


            }



        }


    }
```

First try the numbers 1000, 0.135, and 250.

The expected output is

```
     PAYMENT          MONTHLY          INTEREST          PRINCIPAL          PRINCIPAL
     NUMBER           PAYMENT          PAYMENT           PAYMENT             BALANCE

       1               250.0            11.25              238.75               761.25

       2               250.0            8.56              241.44               519.81

       3               250.0            5.85              244.15               275.66

       4               250.0            3.1              246.9               28.76

       5               29.09            0.32              28.76               0.0
```

And the actual result is indeed the same thing. It works like a charm.

Now try these numbers: 200000, 0.06, and 1500.

For some odd reason, the program ends at entry 141 with a final output of:

```
       141               1500.0            494.88              1005.12               97970.54
```

It ends with exit code 0, no errors, and just simply stops right there.

I know it's a lot to ask for, but I'd appreciate it if someone put the code into their IDE and tinkered with it until they found the problem. Please try the exact numbers I put in this post and see if anything is off, I want to be able to compare the problem to the solution. Apologies again for the messy and amateur code, I'm relatively new to all this still. I appreciate any help, and thanks in advance.

Cheers :D

Comment: Are you using an IDE? Try setting a conditional breakpoint when your payment # is 141, and step through what's happening.

Failing that, stop at payment 141, and inspect every variable. I'd suspect that your loop is exiting due to some condition being satisifed.

What is amtPayments when you put your test input in?

Comment: @ScubaSteve what do you mean by conditional breakpoint? I'm really sorry for not knowing what's going on, but I'm using intelliJ, is that my IDE? And I thought the same things, I believe that the second loop is being satisfied by some condition, but I can't figure out what. EDIT: amtPayments returns 142.0 when I use the example in the post.

Comment: A breakpoint is used in an IDE to stop the code at any point. In most IDE's you can set a conditional breakpoint so that it doesn't stop every time, only when the conditions are met.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-breakpoints.html

Comment: @ScubaSteve I set a breakpoint in the second for loop, and I discovered that it is NOT an issue to do with the second loop. The program gave the same exact output when I inserted a breakpoint on the second loop. It's a problem to do with the first loop ending early. Hope this helps you figure something out? Thanks in advance! You've been a huge help already :)

Comment: That makes sense! Breakpoints are a great help, got me through algorithms & data structures once upon a time.

Comment: Okay, it looks like you're not setting amtPayments at any point between the first loop and second loop. Maybe look at the calculation you're using to get amtPayments? Is the value being initialized correctly?

Comment: It's being initialized, and I used the value in the second for loop: for(int b=0; b<amtPayments-1; b++) is that incorrect usage?

Comment: @ScubaSteve Additionally, my mistake on the comment before previous. I meant to say if statement, not second for loop. The issue at the moment seems to be that the for(int b=0; b<amtPayments-1; b++) is ending early, and the if statement is never fulfilled.

Comment: print amtPayments to console for debugging, or use a breakpoint to stop and inspect the variable, is it correct?

Comment: amtPayments prints as 142.0 when I ask the program to print it right after being calculated. Seems suspicious, as the program ends at 141...

Comment: FYI I used an online amortization calculator, and the total number of entries should end up being between 216 and 228 months, (had to give or take a year) so that's what we're aiming for.

Comment: The program is doing exactly what you tell it to, it's ending when b is no longer less than amtPayments - 1, which is 141.

So, there's something wrong with your amtPayments calculation.

Comment: Holy crap you're right! I hardcoded amtPayments as 221, and it functioned perfectly! I think I've got it from here. You're such a livesaver, thanks so much! EDIT: I'm completely braindead and I have no idea how to determine the amount now. What would you suggest for determining how many payments will be made?

Comment: I have no idea how mortgages are supposed to work, so can't help you there. 

If I had to guess, it'd be the mortgage amount minus the down payment, divided by the monthly payment minus the monthly interest?

Comment: I live in Vancouver, software engineers are too poor to afford houses here :,(

Comment: @ScubaSteve so when I use the formula in the code, where I take the payment amount entered into system.in and apply the interest, it works for the first example well enough. $250 per month - $250 per month times 0.135 = 216.25. Then the overall loan divided by that is 4.62, and I ceil it to get to 5 total payments. When I do it with the second example, I get $1500 per month - $1500 per month times 0.06 which = 1410. $200,000 / 1410 is 141.8. Why doesn't this work for the second one? It must be some disparity within the calculation that doesn't account for something.

Answer (score -2):

Increment b and then use that b instead of b+1,
 before you write this line

```
System.out.println("       " + info[b+1] + "               " + Math.round(finalMPymt * 100.00) / 100.00 + "            " + Math.round(finalIPymt * 100.00) / 100.00 + "              " + Math.round(finalPPymt * 100.00) / 100.00 + "               " + Math.round(finalPBalance * 100.00) / 100.00);
```

Comment: Care to explain your reasoning for why this is the case, if it works at all?

Comment: I got the same output when I tried this, doesn't seem to do anything. Thanks anyways though :)

Comment: Firslty, I dried run your code. Thus, I apologise for wring output
Second of all you have not given what is your desired output ?
Please mention what should come rather than what you are getting and whats wrong !
As I assume you want 141 results for your iteration but  you are only getting 1 result with 141 as key .

I have debugged your code and its giving 141 results as expected .

Else, If you want 142 results as amtPayments variable is set .
Then update this piece of code :
` for(int b=0; b<amtPayments; b++){ `

Comment: we are now aware that the final computation ends at 221, with data similar to the sample provided. The issue is I do not want 141 lines of code, and I need a better way to figure out the number of payments that should be made given the data of how much I pay per month, the yearly interest rate, and the total amount of the loan.

Comment: amtPayments value is 142 but you run loop to amtPayments-1 so it gives 141 results.
But if you want 221 results then your logic to calculate the amtPayments is wrong.
Please check your logic on how to calculate monthly payments.

Comment: yes I am well aware of that, that's what I'm trying to now figure out. Do you have any ideas? Please check the edit I made to the post for details.